# How to access array from a class in c++? (closed)

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, class

I'm writing a copy constructor for my class, Vehicle, but I'm having trouble accessing an array that the class has in this constructor. I set other values using dot notation (vehi.vin) and that works fine, as expected. So I tried to access the array using the same idea vehi.accessories[0] but that seems to return a null value rather than the string that's actually there. And I know when I first initialize the class that this array does have the proper values in it because I can print them out. So my question is, how can I access an array from a class? Am I using dot notation wrong? Can I not use dot notation for arrays? Do I just need a get method?

code -

vehicle.cpp

```
Vehicle::Vehicle(const Vehicle& vehi)
{
//get values and set them equal to the local object's attributes
vin = vehi.vin;

for(int i = 0; i < vehi.numAccessories; i++)
{
    //cout << "get here\n";
    accessories[i] = vehi.accessories[i];
    cout << accessories[i] << " " << vehi.accessories[i] << endl;
}
}
```

how accessories gets its values:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numAccessories; i++) //loop through file until all accessories for the car have been put into the array
{
        getline(fin, accessories[i]); //put accessory in the next spot in the accessory array
        cout << "Accessory " << (i+1) << ": " << accessories[i] << endl;
}
```

main.cpp declaration of Vehicle object. The constructor reads the values in using the file object passed to it.

```
Vehicle temp(fin);
```

vehicle.h

```
private:
    string accessories[50]; //array of accessories stored in string form
```

Edit: When I try calling the copy constructor directly it works fine but when calling the printVehicle() function it seems to get there but fail somehow. The code below does what I want and shows me that the copy constructor works fine, so I guess it's the way it's invoked from printVehicle()

main.cpp:

```
Vehicle test(fin);
test.startAcc();
cout << endl << test.nextAcc() << endl;
Vehicle test2(test);
test2.startAcc();
cout << endl << test2.nextAcc() << endl;
```

Comment: How is `accessories` declared?

Comment: I posted an edit with my declaration of accessories, sorry.

Comment: This should work. There's something else wrong.

Comment: So the dot notation I'm using is correct?

Comment: Yes [filler]. You use the dot on an object regardless of what you want to access from it.

Comment: Or numAccessories has the wrong value.

Comment: How did you initialize the first instance of Vehicle that gets used by this copy constructor?

Comment: Inside of the for loop in the constructor? That can't be right because when I uncomment that cout statement of "get here" it prints out. So that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @ViteFalcon I posted an edit with the initialization.

Comment: @LukeMat: Ah! I get it... so you're passing a handle to a file. How does the copy constructor get invoked then?

Comment: Put a write to mem watch on your array to see if something else is stomping it after it initializes (or it will tell you if it isn't getting initialized.)

Comment: Using static array is not a very good option for class member and I believe the error you are seeing is caused by the assignment of this array. Use `std::vector` instead to avoid trouble.

Comment: Did you define a global variable inside your header? Note that each TU which includes this header will have its own copy. It is not one global array being accessed everywhere.

Comment: I call a function in the main that passes the object by value which invokes the copy constructor.
@MichaelDorgan I'm not sure what a mem watch is but I shall google it.

Comment: For those peeking at this question, I dunno if it helps at all, or how up-to-date this is, but [prior reference to this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433012/how-to-access-array-from-a-class-without-get-methods-c) may shed light on something.

Comment: OP - what is the symptom you see? What do your `cout` statements print?

Comment: @AlokSave no, I'm staying away from global variables, but there are public variables. 
IvayloStrandjev  i know using a static array is not the best option and I was going to use a pointer to dynamically allocate the memory for it but I just want to get this working before I change anything else.

Comment: This cout statement     cout << accessories[i] << " " << vehi.accessories[i] << endl; does not print anything out.

Comment: @LukeMat: Can you change the signature of your `printVehicle(Vehicle vehicle)` to `printVehicle(const Vehicle& vehicle)`. That should get around your problem of copy-constructor issues, if the copy-constructor is to be blamed. If you get the expected result, then we'll know for sure that its something wrong with copy constructor.

Comment: I would love to do that, but the printVehicle function must change attributes in the object in order to get the values in the accessories array and it is a requirement from my professor. The copy constructor must be used!

Comment: @LukeMat actually, no it doesn't. `printVehicle()` shouldn't even be a free-function. It should be a *member* of `Vehicle`  aka: `Vehicle::printOn(std::stream& os)`, at which time you have complete access to the member variables anyway. I don't know what your prof is trying to teach or prove, or whether the instructions you were given were vague or misunderstood, but this is being made a *lot* harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Yeah that does seem a lot easier and I wish I could do that, but he says printVehicle() must be a function in main.cpp that passes the vehicle object by value and forces the copy constructor to be used. I think he wants to make sure the copy constructor is correct.

Comment: @LukeMat: What we're trying to figure out is if the problem is with your copy constructor or with your main constructor that loads info from file. So I guess you're free to do that in the name of finding out the bug.

Comment: I think this question needs a complete runnable example, or at least all the code where `Vehicle`s are created and printed.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the constructor loading values, when I print out all the values in that constructor they are all correct, it just gets funky when the copy constructor is invoked from printVehicle() function.

Comment: @molbdnilo I tried but the question was closed as being too long, specific or something of that nature. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433012/how-to-access-array-from-a-class-without-get-methods-c) has most of the code.

Comment: It was closed as being too localized, and even then you showed lots of detail that wasn't relevant, while omitting some of the actual code that didn't work. How does the copy constructor initialize `counter`? How does `startAcc()` behave? What happens when you trace through this and inspect both vehicles in the debugger?

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I was an idiot all along and forgot to copy the values over in another method the class had that I was using. I completely forgot that I was even using that method at all. But my original question about accessing arrays from a class was answered, so you've helped.